# Prevent Java FileWatcher to process the same file multiple times

Tags: java, reactive-programming

I'm using Java WatchEvent to monitor an external process that creates an external file.

Java create multiple events until the file is eventually completed while the external process is creating the file:

```
Event kind:ENTRY_CREATE. File affected: fileArticoli (16).zip.
Event kind:ENTRY_MODIFY. File affected: fileArticoli (16).zip.
Event kind:ENTRY_MODIFY. File affected: fileArticoli (16).zip.
Event kind:ENTRY_MODIFY. File affected: fileArticoli (16).zip.
```

I need to be awaken at the end of the process when the file creation is done.

I'm exploring Java RX

```
    PublishSubject<WatchEvent> fsEvents = PublishSubject.create();
    fsEvents.subscribe(this);

    ...
    fsEvents.onNext(event);
```

I'm searching for a JavaRx function similar to debounce that triggers when no new events have been triggered  for a period of time es. 2000ms.
Is there such a function in java RX?

Here is a minimal example

```
@Component
public class FileWatcherComponent implements Action1<WatchEvent> {
    Logger logger  = Logger.getLogger("Upload Ordini");
    @Value("${app.ecommerce.dirOrdini}")
    String orderDir;

    WatchService watchService;
    Path path;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        new Thread(()->{

            PublishSubject<WatchEvent> fsEvents = PublishSubject.create();
            fsEvents.throttleWithTimeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS).subscribe(this);

            if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(orderDir)){
                try {
                    watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
                    path = Paths.get(orderDir);
                    path.register(watchService,ENTRY_MODIFY);
                    WatchKey key;
                    while ((key = watchService.take()) != null) {
                        for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                            fsEvents.onNext(event);
                        }
                        key.reset();
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.config(e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

    }

    @Override
    public void call(WatchEvent event) {
        logger.config( "File affected: " + event.context() + ".");
        //Process the file

    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] and a marble diagram which shows all the events that are created and the subscription value you want to get from these.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually in order avoid to process the same file multiple times I used a different approach. Each file can be processed after 2000 ms. The class tries to process all file in a map (mFiles) every 500ms.
Hope the some may take advantage of this solution.
The file is placed in the map by filewatcher and remove after processing.

```
@Component
public class FileWatcherComponent{
    public static final long DELAY = 2000L;
    @Value("${app.ecommerce.dirOrdini}")
    String orderDir;
    WatchService watchService;
    Path path;
    Map<String, Long> mFiles = new HashMap<>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        new Thread(()->{
            if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(orderDir)){
                try {
                    watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
                    path = Paths.get(orderDir);
                    path.register(watchService,ENTRY_MODIFY);
                    WatchKey key;
                    while ((key = watchService.take()) != null) {
                        for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                            mFiles.put(event.context()+"", (new Date()).getTime());
                        }
                        key.reset();
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {}
            }
        }).start();

    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 500)
    public void processFiles(){
        long startfrom = (new Date()).getTime() - DELAY;
        for (String fname : mFiles.keySet()) {
            if (mFiles.get(fname) < startfrom){
                new Thread(()->{
                    try {
                        processFile(fname);
                    } catch (Exception e){
                        logger.config(e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mFiles.remove(fname);
                }).start();
            }
        }
    }

    public void processFile(String fileName) throws Exception{
        //TODO process file
    }

}
```

This solution is based on Spingboot for class init and scheduling.